# how can I call LUIS and get its intent outside the FormFlow

Tags: c#, azure-language-understanding

I'm developing a chatbot with C# through SQL-Server and I need to know what Luis detects.
We need to call LUIS somehow and get an intent return.

For example:  if "hello" is detected as a greeting intent we need to get the word "greeting" in a string.

Thanks.

Comment: Means you need to obtain original request that user make for intent right?

Comment: **LuisResult** class contains all data about request.

Comment: If you are using Microsoft Bot framework, there are plenty of examples for this in both 3.x and 4.x

Answer (score 1):

The flow is like this.

After you have created, trained and published your utterances in your Luis application, get the endpoint URL and from your program make an HTTP request to this api endpoint with the utterance appended to it at the end.

This will return the detected intent, its score and the entities present with the positions.

Based on the intent and entities received you can construct your responses.

If you need premade responses I suggest you use chatbot builders like

1. Dialogflow
2. Microsoft bot framework
3. Alexa Skill kit

Hope this helps

Edit:

The code for getting the intent, as you have asked for in the comments

```
 let result: any = await request({
                            "method": "GET",
                            "uri": url,//Your API endpoint with the utternce appended
                            "json": true,
                            "headers": {
                            "User-Agent": "demo get"
                        }
                    }).then(function (data) {

                       console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your information. The question is: What is the code to call the function that return the detected intent? Thanks

Comment: I use request promise in node js to make the api call. Do you want the specific code???